# How to specify all interfaces for multicast?

Tags: c++, network-programming, multicast, lan

I have two programs (MS VC++) which using multicast - receiver and sender. I test it between desktop PC (Windows 7) and netbook (Windows XP) via WiFi. Desktop PC have WiFi dongle which working in AP mode. If I specify INADDR_ANY in the interface address in the sender program, I get a problem: multicast doesn't reach netbook from desktop PC. If I specify real address of this WiFi interface instead INADDR_ANY - it working fine.

So, I want that my sender program can working on all interfaces. How I can to do that? I have to initialize separate socket for each interface? Or may be it have more elegant possibility?

Comment: When you do not specify the outgoing multicast interface (or specify it as INADDR_ANY), it will use the system's routing table.  In most cases, that means the using the interface that is specified as the default outgoing interface.  In the case of a desktop, that is likely to be your normal network connection (and is usually a connection to a gateway).  I don't know if there is a simple solution to allow you to send to all.

Comment: Windows (as always) is different to what you're used to everywhere else. It has the notion of "default interface" distinct from routing: in the internet properties dialog, there's a little listbox with all the interfaces and up/down buttons to specify an order. That's the option that specifies behaviour for most of the interface-specific networking calls (though I haven't directly checked for multicast!) Dave is right that unbound/INADDR_ANY will select only one interface in an implementation-defined way. Finally, it is normal to have to enumerate the interfaces and create a socket for each.

Answer (score 2):

As previous people said, you have to select your output interface explicitly. If you want to multicast onto different interfaces concurrently, you'll need multiple sockets. In boost::asio, the corresponding call is:

```
boost::asio::ip::udp::socket*  _write;
...
_write->set_option( ip::multicast::outbound_interface( ifAddr.to_v4()));
```